# How container isolation is being achieved for windows containers which use process isolation mode?

Tags: windows, docker, containers, isolation

There are 2 isolation modes for windows containers:

- Process
- Hyper-V

In case of [Hyper-V isolation mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/hyperv-container#hyper-v-isolation) everything is clear:

> each container runs inside of a highly optimized virtual machine and effectively gets its own kernel. The presence of the virtual machine provides hardware-level isolation between each container as well as the container host.

In case [process isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/hyperv-container#process-isolation) mode docs says the next:

> With process isolation, multiple container instances run concurrently on a given host with isolation provided through namespace, resource control, and other process isolation technologies.

Linux uses [namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces) to achieve containers isolation and it is Linux feature.

So how containers isolation is achieved in Windows since Windows actually doesn't have alternative to `Linux namespaces`? Which isolation technologies are being used in Windows case?